# How to bypass Google login verification screen?

Tags: google-account, security, multi-factor-auth

I can't use my phone, and I'd much rather "let it be a hacker". What do I do?
[image]

Comment: What other options you get if you click "More options" ?

Answer (score 2):

Choosing `more options` should let you send an email to a 'backup' account.

Once you're logged in, try [disabling 2-factor authentication](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1064203?hl=en)